# Kohana 2 - force_login isn't working

Tags: php, authentication, kohana

I'm Using Kohana Auth Module, just as below:

```
$username = $this->input->post("username");
if( Auth::instance()->force_login($username) )
{}
else
echo "error";
```

Echo "error".

What am i doing wrong? The user exists in the database!

Answer (score 0):

http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Auth_ORM#force_login

force_login returns nothing so it will always be false.